# need iphone integration of im chat used in phpfox

Tags: php, iphone, ios, phpfox

I want to integrate default IM chat used in phpfox in our iphone application. I am able to do xmpp chat but dont know how to get Jabberid of user from that phpfox IM chat.

Is there any api for integrating this IM chat.

Comment: The IM chat used in phpfox is not a Jabber client so u will never get a JAbberID for IM client of PHPfox. IM doesnt uses open sockets listeners etc. its a simple central webservice based chat, for doing this u have to create a TCP connection between the mobiles which I think is not possible..